# C++ templates: call whichever function matches between 2 choices

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

How can I call the function that matches using C++ templates? For example if I have the functions a and b:

```
void a_impl(string, int){}
void b_impl(int, string){}

template<typename X, typename Y>
void a(X x, Y y){
  a_impl(x, y);
}

template<typename X, typename Y>
void b(X x, Y y){
  b_impl(x, y);
}

template<typename X, typename Y>
void a_or_b(X x, Y y);
```

How do I implement `a_or_b` such that it calls `a(x, y)` if it matches, otherwise call `b(x, y)`?

---

What I'm trying to make is a `for_each` function that can handle these cases:

```
vector<pair<string, int>> v1 = {{"one", 1}, {"two", 2}};

for_each(v1, [](string x, int y){
  cout << x << " " << y << endl;
});

vector<int> v2 = {1, 2, 3};

for_each(v2, [](int x){
  cout << x << endl;
});
```

So far I have it working for both tuples and single variables independently but I want the appropriate version to be selected automatically. Here is my implementation so far; `unpack` is `apply_from_tuple` from this page http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/apply-tuple-to-function.html.

```
template<typename Range, typename Func>
void for_each_unpack(Range && range, Func && func){
  for (auto && element : range){
    using Element = decltype(element);
    unpack(std::forward<Func>(func), std::forward<Element>(element));
  }
}

template<typename Range, typename Func>
void for_each_nounpack(Range && range, Func && func){
  for (auto && element : range){
    using Element = decltype(element);
    std::forward<Func>(func)(std::forward<Element>(element));
  }
}
```

Edit: Got it working thanks to @jotik. I put the code on github https://github.com/csiz/for_each.

Comment: Make `a` and `b` the same name.

Comment: Works for the specific example, but doesn't for a templated one like my for_each. You'd get redefinition of template... for_each. (I edited the example so it reflects my problem better.)

Comment: Have you heard of SFINAE?  Tag dispatching?  Traits classes?

Comment: Yes I did. Tried using result_of(...)* = nullptr as a template parameter, but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a trailing return type with `decltype` and [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>


void a(std::string, int) { std::cout << "a" << std::endl; }
void b(int, std::string) { std::cout << "b" << std::endl; }

template <typename ... Args>
auto a_or_b(Args && ... args)
    -> decltype(a(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{ return a(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

template <typename ... Args>
auto a_or_b(Args && ... args)
    -> decltype(b(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{ return b(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

int main() {
    std::string s;
    int i;
    a_or_b(s, i); // calls a
    a_or_b(i, s); // calls b
}
```

I've used perfect forwarding in the above example because it avoids a copy for each argument, but the less general naive solution with explicit types also works:

```
template <typename X, typename Y>
auto a_or_b(X x, Y y) -> decltype(a(x, y))
{ return a(x, y); }

template <typename X, typename Y>
auto a_or_b(X x, Y y) -> decltype(b(x, y))
{ return b(x, y); }
```

How SFINAE works in this case is as follows. Note that there are 2 template definitions for `a_or_b`. And when you write a function call to `a_or_b` the compiler tries to figure out which `a_or_b` you meant to call. Due to SFINAE, it ignores any template `a_or_b` for which it is unable to deduce the type for. E.g. for the call `a_or_b(s, i);` the (trailing) return type `decltype(b(std::forward<Args>(args)...))` for the second `a_or_b` definition does not work, therefore the second `a_or_b` definition is not considered by the compiler.

In this case the return type is required to be a trailing return type, because it depends on the function arguments. For example, the following would not compile:

```
template <typename ... Args>
decltype(b(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) a_or_b(Args && ... args)
{ return b(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked and I put the code on github https://github.com/csiz/for_each

Comment: @csiz Note that identifiers starting with underscores (`_`) are reserved.

Comment: Technically it's `__` or `_Caps` that are reserved but I removed the `_` since they weren't useful.

Comment: @csiz Technically in the global namespace all names beginning with underscores are also reserved to the standard library implementations for use according to C++11 §17.6.4.3.2. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting variation of your idea.  Pass a tuple of functions and a pack of arguments.  Then call up all the functions from that tuple (from left to right), that can accept those given arguments.  Furthermore, store all the return values (if any) from those functions called in a tuple.  Here I'm using the `void_t` (`std::void_t` in C++17) aspect of SFINAE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <std::size_t N, typename VoidTFailed, typename EnableIfFailed, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
struct Try {
    static bool execute (Tuple&&, Args&&...) {
        std::cout << "No function found.\n";
        return false;
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename VoidTFailed, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
struct Try<N, VoidTFailed, std::enable_if_t<(N < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value)>, Tuple, Args...> : std::conditional_t<(N < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1),
    Try<N+1, void, void, Tuple, Args...>,
    Try<N+1, int, int, Tuple, Args...>  // If N == std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1, then simply inherit from the primary template above, as inheriting from Try<N+1, void, void, Tuple, Args...> will cause a compiling error when std::tuple_element_t<N+1, Tuple> is instantiated in the specialization below.
> {};

struct NoReturnValue {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const NoReturnValue&) {
        return os << "[no value returned]";
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename EnableIfFailed, typename... Args>
struct Continue {
    static auto execute (Tuple&& functionTuple, Args&&... args) {
        const auto singleTuple = std::make_tuple (std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple))(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
        return std::tuple_cat (singleTuple, Try<N+1, void, void, Tuple, Args...>::execute(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename... Args>  // This specialization is only used if the function in question returns void.
struct Continue<N, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<decltype(std::declval<std::tuple_element_t<N, std::decay_t<Tuple>>>()(std::declval<std::decay_t<Args>>()...))>::value>, Args...> {
    static auto execute (Tuple&& functionTuple, Args&&... args) {
        std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return std::tuple_cat (std::make_tuple(NoReturnValue{}), Try<N+1, void, void, Tuple, Args...>::execute(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename EnableIfFailed, typename... Args>
struct Stop {
    static auto execute (Tuple&& functionTuple, Args&&... args) {
        return std::make_tuple (std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple))(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename... Args>  // This specialization is only used if the function in question returns void.
struct Stop<N, Tuple, std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<decltype(std::declval<std::tuple_element_t<N, std::decay_t<Tuple>>>()(std::declval<std::decay_t<Args>>()...))>::value>, Args...> {
    static auto execute (Tuple&& functionTuple, Args&&... args) {
        std::get<N>(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        return std::make_tuple(NoReturnValue{});
    }
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Tuple, typename... Args>
struct Try<N, void_t<decltype(std::declval<std::tuple_element_t<N, Tuple>>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>,
        std::enable_if_t<(N < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value)>, Tuple, Args...> : std::conditional_t<(N < std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1),
    Continue<N, Tuple, void, Args...>,
    Stop<N, Tuple, void, Args...>
> {};

template <typename Tuple, typename... Args>
auto executeAllPossible (Tuple&& functionTuple, Args&&... args) {
    return Try<0, void, void, Tuple, Args...>::execute(std::forward<Tuple>(functionTuple), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

// Testing
int foo (int, char, bool, int, int) {std::cout << "foo\n";  return 8;}
bool bar (int, char, bool, double, long, bool) {std::cout << "bar\n";  return true;}
void goo (int, char&&, bool, float, int) {std::cout << "goo\n";}
double baz (int, const char, bool&&, double, std::size_t) {std::cout << "baz\n";  return 4.5;}

template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
void print_tuple_impl (std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, const Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using A = int[];
    (void)A{(void(os << (Is == 0 ? "" : ", ") << std::get<Is>(t)), 0)...};
}

template <typename Ch, typename Tr, typename... Args>
decltype(auto) operator<< (std::basic_ostream<Ch, Tr>& os, const std::tuple<Args...>& t) {
    os << "tuple{";
    print_tuple_impl(os, t, std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{});
    return os << "}";
}

int main() {
    const auto tuple = executeAllPossible (std::make_tuple(foo, bar, goo, baz), 2, 'c', true, 3.5, 8);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "output = " << tuple << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
foo  goo  baz
output = tuple{8, [no value returned], 4.5}
```